# gatling- am I doing it right?

Tags: gatling

I am new to gatling and I just want to know if I am doing it right. Here is the scenario.

I am running an application on my local instance, created a simple gatling test to login (with specific credentials), answer a survey(has a specific id) and logout. I have 'testdb' loaded for this app. I run the test, it gives me the result- everything is fine and perfect.

Now I change the testdb to proddb. Note that login creds will be different. so if I run the same test on this new one, I see a few 401 and remotely closed exceptions; but the login part of the test works fine (which as per my understanding should fail- since they are not the old creds). this in the reports shows up as a passed test. How could this happen? Please help. Any explanation as to what is happening and where am I doing wrong will be gladly taken.

Thank you!

Comment: Actually, none of your code was actually posted. Then, do you run the same load on both platforms? Your test might simply have highlighted bugs in your system?

Comment: can you please elaborate on what you mean by not posted? I ran the test with one single user on both platforms. Here is what I did: I created the test from the recorder and then run it from the console and I see the test pass completely when I use the testdb and it partially passed(as i said login test passed which should not) on the prod db.